# Can somebody explain the errors while sending sms through smsgateway.me api?

Tags: php, vb.net, http

I am trying to post request through vb.net.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Public Class TestSMS
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Try
            Dim webAddr As String = "https://smsgateway.me/api/v4/message/send"
            Dim httpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(webAddr), HttpWebRequest)
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
            Dim header As WebHeaderCollection = New WebHeaderCollection()
            header.Add("Authorization", "** Key Hidden for security **")
            httpWebRequest.Headers = header
            Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                Dim json As String = "{'phone_number':'123456789','message':'Hello World','device_id':116}"
                streamWriter.Write(json)
                streamWriter.Flush()
            End Using
            Dim httpResponse = CType(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                Dim responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                MsgBox(responseText)
            End Using
        Catch ex As WebException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I got

> 400 Bad request error.

Here is an example of code https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/messages/sending-a-sms-message

but it is in PHP.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, for a start. JSON property names, and string values, must be double-quoted, not single-quoted

Comment: Also, you are sending an object instead of an array. From those examples of the input content, you must wrap your object in an array (because it's evidently possible to send multiple messages in the same HTTP request).

Comment: Also, that PHP code is not very relevant here because it's relying a ready-made PHP client library. More useful would be for you to study that library and see how it constructs the actual HTTP request (which is analogous to what your VB code is doing).

Comment: Or since this API supports Swagger, you could use a tool to generate a .NET client for the API automatically, based on the Swagger definition. That would save you the trouble of trying to get the details of the HTTP request right yourself, and you could just focus on sending/receiving the data itself, and on the rest of the business logic of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json


Public Class TestSMS
    Public Class Messageparam
        Public Property phone_number As String
        Public Property message As String
        Public Property device_id As Integer
    End Class
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim messageParam As New Messageparam
        messageParam.phone_number = "123456789"
        messageParam.message = "Hello World!"
        messageParam.device_id = 116
        Dim webAddr As String = "https://smsgateway.me/api/v4/message/send"
        Dim httpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(webAddr), HttpWebRequest)
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
        Dim header As WebHeaderCollection = New WebHeaderCollection()
        header.Add("Authorization", "Hidden API Key")
        httpWebRequest.Headers = header
        Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            Dim json As String = "[" & JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageParam) & "]"
            streamWriter.Write(json)
            streamWriter.Flush()
        End Using
        Dim httpResponse = CType(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```